# xmpppy: how to get auth response from server

Tags: python, python-2.7, xmpppy

Upon registration attempt, server sends a message containing a token, which should later be passed in messages during the conversation. Something like

```
{
 "from" : "jid@server",
 "to" : "jid@client",
 "type" : "token",
 "token" : "T0K3N"
}
```

I tried the simple client connection sequence:

```
c = xmpp.Client('myClient')
c.connect(server=(localhost, 5222))
c.auth('jid', 'password')
```

And connection establishes successfully. However, I'm not getting token from server. How can I listen and consume the reply?

Edit: I see that server tries to send the token, but fails with "cannot relay to offline receiver" message. Do I connect incorrectly?